# Convert Timestamp to image?

Tags: sql-server, image, t-sql, timestamp

I was looking at the CAST and CONVERT specification on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), and the SQL Server datatype conversion chart (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35834) allows for an implicit conversion between a timestamp and an image.

My question is - what would the result of this be (what would the image even look like?!), and what uses are there for this conversion? Or is image not what I think it is?

Comment: Image is not a picture, but a binary string. Useful for storing small files and all manner of other content, but not worth 1000 words. More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).

Comment: `image` isn't what you think, and nor, probably, is `timestamp`. Both describe binary formats.

Comment: Try it for yourself - they look exactly the same. As has been said they are both just binary data. -----  `DECLARE @T TABLE (TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL); INSERT @T DEFAULT VALUES; SELECT TS, CONVERT(IMAGE, TS) FROM @T;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is image not what I think it is?

Indeed. As you assume that images are pictures. It certainly is not.

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

> **image**
>
> Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
>   bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this:

```
select cast(cast(GETDATE() as timestamp) as image)

select cast(cast(0x0000A49900F64E99 as image) as timestamp)
```

Comment: The `timestamp` datatype has nothing to do with dates and times. The newer and more informative name is [`rowversion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx).